# database query limitation

Tags: mysql, database

So, I have this mysql query:

`SELECT member_id, text FROM review WHERE text != "" ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2`

This returns the latest two reviews, my question is can I somehow restrict this query returning two rows with the same member_id? I've tried adding `DISTINCT` before member_id but has no effect.

Comment: No, he wants two rows with the same member_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group by. But if you have more than two rows for the same id, you cannot know which text will come.

```
    SELECT r.member_id, r.text 
    FROM review r, (Select member_id, max(date) dat from review WHERE text != "" group by member_id) t1      
    WHERE r.member_id =t1.member_id and t1.dat=r.date
    LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about using group by but I need the latest text

Comment: @pinkypower if your date is correct. The query should be valid. did you try the query?

Comment: Yes, I did, it returns 2 months old results

Comment: @pinkypower : could you provide input and output expecting??

Comment: @pinkypower try max() function

Comment: This solution is wrong. pinkypower wants to have two rows with same member_id. GROUP BY will give one row per member_id. Shiplu's answer is right.

Comment: @tombom I thought he will have only the latest one with max date

Answer (score 1):

> can I somehow restrict this query returning two rows with the **same `member_id`**?

If your member Id is MEMBERID you can use this query.

```
SELECT member_id, 
       TEXT 
FROM   review 
WHERE  TEXT != "" 
       AND member_id = memberid 
ORDER  BY DATE DESC 
LIMIT  2
```